# How can you restore merges to a certain state?

Tags: git, github

We have a project with several branches. The project is now in an out-of-date state - probably because of an merging that someone made.
It is possible to return to a previous version of the main branch?

We've tried all sorts of commands that restore commits, but I'm trying to get to the state of a certain merging branch after pull requests was done to him. How can I do it, because it is not one merging?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to add more detail. Resetting a branch is not terribly difficult, but you haven't explained what specific problem you're having.

Comment: "*It is possible to return to a previous version of the main branch?*" Yes, but the overall question is too unclear for us to make any somewhat safe assumption about your context. Like @isherwood suggested, you'd better rework your question a bit, I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution, **but it is very harmful so you can use it at your own risk**:

```bash
# Backup your master into a different branch

git branch master-backup
git push git push --set-upstream origin master-backup

# Return to master

git checkout master

# Search for the commit you need to restore to

git log --oneline

# Then write down the commit hash...

# Do a hard reset

git reset --hard <COMMIT-HASH-YOU-WROTE-DOWN>

# Attention!!! Rewrite the REMOTE git MASTER branch history!!!

git push origin master --force
```

Comment: They already tried "*all sorts of commands that restore commits*". If they've already reset the branch to some past point, the `git log --oneline` could very well miss crucial parts. The wanted hash **might** be only findable through reflog now. Thus the reason for asking more details.

Comment: As you can see I created a backup of the master that can be used to cherry pick some missing commit.